# Eliminar registros si cumplen cierta condicion

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Hola cordiales saludos a todos,

Me encuentro trabajando con Excel y vba, con la grabadora de Macros hice lo siguiente:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(RC[-1]=24,""REVIEW"",IF(RC[-1]=25,""REVIEW"",IF(RC[-1]=50,""REVIEW"",IF(RC[-1]=75,""REVIEW"",IF(RC[-1]=100,""REVIEW"",""DELETE"")))))"
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es la columna "L" tiene "X" cantidad de registros que obtengo de otro libro **Excel**, en esa columna hay valores numéricos y vacíos.

Lo que hice fue meter el IIF arriba posteado y si en la columna hay ciertos valores: 24, 25, 50, 75, 100 entonces agrego en la columna "M" uel texto "**REVIEW**" si no entonces agrego "**DELETE**" para posteriormente meter un filtro y eliminar todos aquellos que en la columna "M" digan **DELETE**.

Lo que quiero hacer es pasar ese código a un ciclo, pero en principios como le indico al **for** posicionarte en la columna "L,2" y que comience el ciclo.

```
   Dim UltimaFila As Long

'Detecta la última fila del rango de datos en la hoja activa
Range("L2").Select
UltimaFila = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
```

For i = 2 To 65536 'Obtengo el error 6 overflow

```
Select Case Cells(i, 2).Value
    Case Is = 24
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "REVIEW"
    Case Is = 25
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "REVIEW"
    Case Is = 50
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "REVIEW"
    Case Is = 75
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "REVIEW"
    Case Is = 100
        Cells(i, 3).Value = "REVIEW"
End Select
```

Next i

Ya encontre como posicionarme en la columna que requiero y obtener la ultima fila de la columna. Pero ahora obtengo el siguiente error:

Run-time-error 6
Overflow

A que se debe el error?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

DS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque tu problema es tan sencillo como que seguramente has declarado `Dim i As Integer` y no puede superar el 65536, bastaría con cambiar `Integer` por `Long`.

No obstante te pongo aquí otro método más eficiente para hacer lo que quieres.

Está todo explicado por el código:

```
Option Explicit 'pon esto siempre arriba del todo de tus módulos, te obliga a declarar todas tus variables
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TuHoja") 'cambia TuHoja por el nombre de la hoja
        'creamos un array en el que introduciremos toda la hoja
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = .UsedRange.Value

        'creamos un segundo array igual de grande que el primero para meter únicamente lo que necesitamos
        Dim arrFinal As Variant
        ReDim arrFinal(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To UBound(arr, 2))

        'Siempre que declares variables numéricas utiliza Long en lugar de integer
        Dim i As Long, x As Long, j As Long
        x = 2 'iniciamos la x

        'ponemos los encabezados en el nuevo array
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arrFinal(1, i) = arr(1, i)
        Next i

        'hacemos un bucle para comprobar todas las filas
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
            'la columna 12 es la L, así que buscamos en la coordenada 12 para la columna del array (siempre y cuando haya datos
            'desde la columna A)
            If arr(i, 12) = 24 Or arr(i, 12) = 25 Or arr(i, 12) = 50 Or arr(i, 12) = 75 Or arr(i, 12) = 100 Then
                arr(i, 13) = "REVIEW" 'le ponemos el REVIEW

                'hacemos un bucle para pegar todas las columnas en el nuevo array (que no contendrá los que hubieras puesto "DELETE"
                For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
                    arrFinal(x, j) = arr(i, j)
                Next j

                'incrementamos la x para el array final
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i

        'pegamos el array final en la hoja
        .UsedRange.Value = arrFinal

        'eliminamos las filas extra
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Rows(i & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias Damian, por la aportación.
Hice la correción de mi ciclo for de Integer por Long, lo ejecute y ahora funciona.
Probe el array aportado y simplemente es mucho mas rapido que mi ciclo for.
Con el codigo comentado me sera mas fácil entenderlo a detalle.
NOTA: Solo corregi la variable Dim arrFinal As Variant ya que estaba declarado como Long y marcaba error que faltaba declarar el Array.
Muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Cierto es @JoseDanielSolis! un pequeño lapsus mental. Por eso te he puesto los arrays, cuando trabajas con cantidades grandes de datos, trabajar directamente sobre excel lo vuelve lento, así que es mejor trabajar en memoria(los arrays) y al final volcar el resultado a excel.